# Processing Groups of Results with Vertx - How to coordinate?

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

I have a job processing system where each job contains thousands of individual tasks that require different strategies to complete. The individual tasks make up the whole job. If all tasks have been completed, the job is marked as successfully completed and other steps are taken, if any of the tasks fail, the job must be marked as failed and other steps are taken, if the job times out the job must be marked as failed and other steps are taken.

Once all of the results for a job have been received, the next job can be fetched. The next job shouldn't be fetched while a job is currently being processed.

Here is the what the flow looks like:

[image]

The Job Polling Verticle publishes a job to the event bus, and the Job Processing Verticle publishes each task to the event bus. When the job strategy completes, it publishes the task result to the event bus.

The issue is that I don't know the *right* way to determine when all tasks have been completed in this model. All verticles are stateless, The Job Processing Verticle doesn't await any futures, and even if the Job Results Verticle was stateful, it doesn't know how many results it should expect.

The only way I can think to do this would be to have a global stateful object. But I don't think this is good design.

[image]

Additionally, I need to know when a Job has *timed out*. That is, it's run longer than it should and I need to consider it's failed, log it, and move on.

I could do this with the global state, but again I don't think that's the right solution.

Does this verticle pattern make sense for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me try to address your questions. Then I'll try to explain what problems this design has.

> The issue is that I don't know the right way to determine when all tasks have been completed in this model. All verticles are stateless, The Job Processing Verticle doesn't await any futures, and even if the Job Results Verticle was stateful, it doesn't know how many results it should expect.

The solution could be reference counting verticle. Each worker should emit a `start message` on event bus with `jobId` when it starts, and `end message` with `jobId` when it completes. Even if you have fan-out (those are the cases that you don't know how many workers there are), counting verticle will know that. In your diagram, "Job Post Processing Verticle" is a good candidate for this. It can maintain a counter, and only when it reaches zero, it should start the next job. That also helps avoiding actually sharing some memory reference.

> Additionally, I need to know when a Job has timed out. That is, it's run longer than it should and I need to consider it's failed, log it, and move on.

In the same verticle you can start a timer every time you get a new `start message`. If you get `end message`, cancel the timer. Otherwise, cancel current job and start again.

Now, this solution will work, but the design has two main flaws. One is the fact that you maintain all your flow in memory, it seems. If your application crashes, all progress is lost, and it's not clear how you record it. Maybe polling `Jobs` table in DB would actually be better, since your job execution is sequential anyway.

Second point is the fact that all those timeouts and reference counting is homemade implementation of structured concurrency. Maybe you should take a look at something like Kotlin coroutines for that, at it will handle many of your problems for you.

Comment: This all makes sense. I see your point in regards to fault tolerance. We are backed by a queue, but unfortunately we cannot replay tasks after they've been completed. So if a job partially completes before failing, we just have to mark the job as failed and continue. If we could replay jobs, we wouldn't delete the message from the queue and retry it after the visibility timeout.